# Python OpenPyxl How to insert a shape for text

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

How do you use the openpyxl.drawing to insert text, like a text box in or on top of a chart.

I can  add an image:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test.jpg')
img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('guage.xlsx')
```

But I would like to add text on top of a chart or in the chart object.
I don't see any examples other than image and this doesn't work:

```
from openpyxl.drawing import shape
...
ws.add_shape(txtBox)
```

AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.drawing.shape' has no attribute 'add_shape'
Is there any examples on adding drawing objects other than the image?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported in openpyxl.